How to use Advanced Search in Bugzilla to retrieve bug reports before 2019
I have a question now. I want to get all the bug reports of a certain component of bugzilla-mozilla, but the results I get when I use Advanced Search are only those after 2019.
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/query.cgi?format=advanced
Why is that? (Bug reports before 2019 can be found using the bug id, but they are not displayed in the Advanced Search query results)
